# Increase the gap between "Award a bounty" buttons

Tags: bug, design, bounty

If an answer was previously awarded a bounty, the next "Award a bounty" button is displayed below without any gap:

[image]

([link to the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300034/sending-ctrla-combination-to-an-element)).

Comment: ​+1 Because this has nothing to do with hats

Answer (score 1):

For the record, all it'd take to fix it is:

```css
.vote .bounty-award-container + .bounty-award-container {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Just in case someone wants to make a userstyle for it.